# $X$ and $Y$ are unformly distributed in $[0,1]$ with $P(\max(X,Y)≤z)=P(\min(X,Y)≤(1−z))$. Find $z$.

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

**Problem:** Two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ are uniformly distributed in the interval $[0,1]$. For a $z \in [0,1]$, we are told that $P(\max(X,Y)\le z)=P(\min(X,Y)\le (1-z))$. Then, what is the value of $z$?

What is meant by $\max(X,Y)$? Can anyone please help me by giving hints?

Comment: $\max(X,Y)$ is the maximum value of $X$ or $Y$.

Comment: Okay. But how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

If the maximum of two values is at least as great as $z$ then they both are.

If the minimum of two values is at least as great as $(1-z)$ then at least one is.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P\big(\max(X,Y)\leq z\big)
 & = \mathsf P(X\leq z\cap Y\leq z)
\\[2ex]
\mathsf P\big(\min(X,Y)\leq (1-z)\big)
 & =\mathsf P\big(X\leq (1-z)\cup Y\leq (1-z)\big)
\end{align}$$

Now you have independent and identically distributed uniform random values.  Evaluate and find the value of $z$ which makes these qualities equal.

Comment: Thank you. I got the answer $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.